# SQL - select sample values of column1 ofr each distinct value of column2

Tags: sql

I have a following table:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| one | a |
| two | a |
| 333 | b |
| 323 | b |

How do I get for each distinct value present in col2  only 1 corresponding value in col1 lie the following:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| one | a |
| 323 | b |

Comment: What is the data type of col1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select col2,min(col1)x
 from your_table
  group by col2;
```